# hide the form after button form pressed javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, button, show-hide

Ok, here is the thing.

I have posted 2 days in a row and you guys have helped me a lot! And know I am almost done with the project, only a few things left, and a will ask another question later here.

But to the point!
I am trying to use the .style.display = ... in my javascript and it doesnt work.
I dont know if the function isnt calling or if I have done it all wrong?

What I am trying to accomplish is that when I press the button "newButton" I got a form field, and after I am finished with the form I press the button "addContact" that is created with the form all dynamically with javascript I want the form to hide. How can I do that?

The form is not gonna submit to a php and that is why a have button and not submit, because the form is gonna display at the HTML (DOM) and show like a contactlist.

Hope you could help me out!
Here is the code.

```
    //Contactlist funktion
function Contact(fname, lname, address, email, phone) { 
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.address = address;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
}

//The contacts
var contacts = [];

var ul1 = document.createElement('ul');
    ul1.id = ('nav');

// Appending the objects
function theContacts() {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
        length = contacts.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var cont = contacts[i],
            li = document.createElement('li'),
            ul = document.createElement('ul');
         li.innerHTML = cont.fname + ' ' + cont.lname;
        for (var key in cont) {
            var info = document.createElement('li');
            info.className = key;
            info.innerHTML = cont[key];
            ul.appendChild(info);
        }
        li.appendChild(ul); ul1.appendChild(li);
    }
    body.appendChild(ul1);
}

// Calling the object
function addForms(){
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.id = 'formList';
    var myArray = ['fnameValue', 'lnameValue', 'addressValue', 'emailValue', 'phoneValue'];
    var texts = ['First Name: ', 'Last Name: ', 'Address: ', 'Email: ', 'Phone: '];

// Create a loop of 5 
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    var newlabel = document.createElement('label');
        newlabel.innerHTML = texts[i];
    form.appendChild(newlabel);
    input.setAttribute('type','text');
    input.setAttribute('id', myArray[i]);

    // adds the input's to the form.
    form.appendChild(input);
    }

    // adds the forms to the body
    body.appendChild(form);

    // Add Contact Button
    var addContact = document.createElement('input')
        addContact.setAttribute('type', 'button')
        addContact.setAttribute('id', 'addContact')
        addContact.addEventListener('click', onClick);
        addContact.setAttribute('value', 'Add Contact')
        form.appendChild(addContact);

/*    var knapp = document.getElementById('addContact');
        knapp.addEventListener('click', addNewContact)   */   
}

function addNewContact() {
        var input1 = document.getElementById('fnameValue').value;
        var input2 = document.getElementById('lnameValue').value;
        var input3 = document.getElementById('addressValue').value;
        var input4 = document.getElementById('emailValue').value;
        var input5 = document.getElementById('phoneValue').value;
    contacts.length = 0;
    contacts.push(new Contact(input1, input2, input3, input4, input5));
    }

// Knappning för ny kontakt
var button = document.getElementById("newButton");
button.addEventListener("click", addForms);
```

Here is the last part of the code that I am trying to apply but doesnt work for me...

```
function onClick() {
    var div = document.getElementById('formlist');
    if (addForms.style.display !== 'none') {
        addForms.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        addForms.style.display = 'block';
    }
};
```

Here you have an JS FIDDLE for example: http://jsfiddle.net/192ds38a/
That one shows how it works now withuot the "onClick" function. 
But what I want is to hide the form when the AddContact button is pressed. That button is now made to add the information to the objects, but I also want that to hide the form.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle to show us your problem more clearly?

Comment: As a general rule, this type of Javascript design, where you create everything on the fly, is considered poor. Better is to create everything in HTML, and just hide/show what you need. Dynamic forms should only be used for things that can't be pre-created, such as a dynamic number of rows in a tabular form.

Comment: @k-nut here you have a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/192ds38a/
That one shows how it works now withuot the "onClick" function. 
But what I want is to hide the form when the AddContact button is pressed. That button is now made to add the information to the objects, but I also want that to hide the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a `document.getElementById("formList").remove()`to the `addNewContact` function as you can see in http://jsfiddle.net/192ds38a/1/ . Or does this not meet your needs?

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks! Do you know a way that lets the "formlist" be always on top? Because now it gets below every contact.

Comment: Or if I change my question. If I want this to show as a "box" on top of the contacts, similar like a popup? Like if you have your phone and then you want to add something to a calender or add a new contact, then a "popup" inside the app/window comes up on top of everything. I dont know if I could explain myslef here..

Comment: If you want a good looking popup on top of your content you might for example want to use bootstrap modals as seen here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals This will require you to include the library and write som additional javascript though...